# How to handle direct file upload with GAE/python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Client side (javascript) uploads the application with `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('POST', my_app_url, false);
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", req.length);
  req.sendAsBinary(req.binary);
```

I use datastore on the server side (not blobstore).
How can I save uploaded file to the datastore? I've found that `ServletFileUpload` can be used with Java. But how to do the same with Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `self.request.body`

```
class YourUploadHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        your_binary_content = self.request.body
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean on the appengine side, you just have to have a blobproperty.  So something like...

```
class SomeEntity(db.Model):
    file_data = db.BlobProperty()

class AddData(webapp.RequestHandler)
    def post(self):
        data = self.request.get("filedata")
        e = SomeEntity(file_data = db.Blob(data))
        e.put()
```

As a note, I'm not sure if the code you posted above to send the request is correct, but you can upload the file with a simple html form, something like this:

```
<form action="/url_to_adddata_handler/" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="filedata">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't have the form. So I cannot use `self.request.get("filedata")`, but looks like `self.request.body` does what I need ;).